# Inner Classes variable Access

Tags: dialog, this, box

In this case I'm a little confused as to why I can't use myFrame as the first parameter in the showMessageDialog function. Why doesn't this work?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class BabyCalculator extends JFrame{

public BabyCalculator(){
    //You set this up so that you can refer to the frame using the inner class below.
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setName("Baby Calculator");
    setLayout(new GridLayout(3,0));
    //add
    JLabel addLabel = new JLabel("Amount to add:");
    JTextField addField = new JTextField(10);
    JButton addButton = new JButton("add");
    addButton.addActionListener(new AddListener());
    //multiply
    JLabel multiplyLabel = new JLabel("Amount to multiply:");
    JTextField multiplyField = new JTextField(10);
    JButton multiplyButton = new JButton("multiply");
    //total
    JLabel totalLabel = new JLabel("Total");
    JTextField totalField = new JTextField(10);
    totalField.setEditable(false);
    JButton stopButton = new JButton("Stop");
    stopButton.addActionListener(new StopListener());
    //Create Panels
    JPanel topRow = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JPanel middleRow = new JPanel (new BorderLayout());
    JPanel bottomRow = new JPanel (new FlowLayout());
    //Add the top Row
    topRow.add(addLabel,BorderLayout.WEST);
    topRow.add(addField, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    topRow.add(addButton, BorderLayout.EAST);
    add(topRow);

    middleRow.add(multiplyLabel,BorderLayout.WEST);
    middleRow.add(multiplyField, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    middleRow.add(multiplyButton, BorderLayout.EAST);
    add(middleRow);

    bottomRow.add(totalLabel);
    bottomRow.add(totalField);
    bottomRow.add(stopButton);

    add(bottomRow);



    pack();
    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main (String[] args){
    JFrame myFrame = new BabyCalculator();
}

public class AddListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(myFrame, "You Clicked the add button");

    }
}
//end class AddListener

public class StopListener implements ActionListener{//this is an inner class
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(myFrame, "You Clicked the stop button");
    }//end class StopListener
}
```

}

I know that this is an inner class, and I'm not exactly sure about the access privileges, but it seems like there should be some way to access the "myFrame" variable in the main function.

Answer (score 0):

Add a declaration statement at the top within the BabyCalculator class as:

```
JFrame myFrame;
```

Or you could make it a public variable with:

```
public JFrame myFrame = ...
```